# How to make Grafana send alert messages with values coming from relational database query

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-alerts

I have a grafana dashboard.
And I need to send alerts messages with especific values.

**I need an alert message with values returned by query (text, tags).**

Time series query:
[image: TimeSeries query from MySQL]

Alert configuration:

[image: Alert Configuration]

I'm receiving this alert:
[image]

**As we see, I tried diffent ways to get the values, but don't work.**

I'm receiving this:
Quantity of requests per minute from $ is gretter than $.

But I want this:
Quantity of requests per minute from [TAG NAME] is gretter than [COUNT].